# Unable to add a subsequent node on a VMM HA Cluster

Tags: windows-cluster, scvmm

Due to assortment of problems, a planned VMM Cluster was only created with a single node. When the second node was later added and joined to the cluster, VMM could not be installed.

The following error was believed to be related to the cause:

```
10:03:15:VMMPostinstallProcessor threw an exception: Threw Exception.Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException, Exception.Message: External component has thrown an exception.
10:03:15:StackTrace: at CCertificate.ImportCertificateInMyStoreAndAssociateWithKey(shared_ptr<CCertificate>* , basic_string<unsigned short\,std::char_traits<unsigned short>\,std::allocator<unsigned short> >* , shared_ptr<unsigned char>* , UInt32 )
at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Certificates.CertificateHelper.ImportPangaeaCertForSSLFromKeyContainer(String certSubjectName, String portNumber, Byte[] certBlob)
at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Setup.IndigoCertificateHelper.CreateVMMCertificate()
at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Setup.InstallItemCustomDelegates.PangaeaServerPostinstallProcessor()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, a Cumulative Update to VMM was installed on the first cluster node before the second node was added. This is believed to be the source of the problem.

In order to resolve the matter, it was necessary to [uninstall VMM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610571(v=sc.12).aspx) from the first node while [retaining the database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3132774) in order to avoid a complete rebuild of the system.

Once removal was complete, VMM was reinstalled on both nodes. The Cumulative Update was installed *after* the installation on both nodes.

For anyone attempting to replicate the fix, it should be noted that there are two separate SQL operations that need to be performed on the VMM database. One operation is ran after the removal of VMM and the second is ran after VMM has been installed on all nodes.

These scripts are referenced in the above link to a Microsoft Support article regarding database retention and VMM reinstallation.